# How to make a portable, cross-platform, TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt USB stick?

Tags: macos, truecrypt

I'm using VeraCrypt, a fork of TrueCrypt.  TrueCrypt had a mode called "Traveller Mode" on Windows, that allows for the encrypted volume/file to be accessed without requiring an installation of TrueCrypt itself.

Unfortunately this functionality is not in the Mac version (nor is it in VeraCrypt).  I want to have a USB stick that will be accessible on both Mac and Windows (with the password), without anyone having to install anything first.

I have tried creating two volumes using FAT format - 1 that is encrypted and 1 smaller one that is not, then placing a copy of the installed VeraCrypt.app onto the unencrypted volume.  Unfortunately that copy of the app crashes when launched on a computer without VeraCrypt installed.

Is there a way to create a portable, cross platform, encrypted USB stick with VeraCrypt or TrueCrypt on a Mac running OSX Mavericks and if so, what is it?

Comment: I remember I needed administrator/root permission whenever I run veracrypt or true crypt to decrypt containers. I don't think it will be possible though.

Comment: Yeah I'm admin/root so that's not an issue here.

Comment: [Portable Mode](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Portable%20Mode)?

Comment: Unfortunately, "Portable Mode" is not available in the Mac version, as stated in my question.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you ask _Is there a way to create a portable, cross platform, encrypted USB stick with VeraCrypt or TrueCrypt on a Mac running OSX Mavericks_, are you asking if there is a way to **create your portable** USB on the Mac, or are you asking if there is a way to create a portable USB that will also run on a Mac with OS X Mavericks?

Comment: Create it with my mac and be able to access it on both windows and mac.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem. If you have no choice but to initially create it on your Mac, then the only suggestion I have is trying to create it using Bootcamp or a virtual Windows environment. However, this is not something I've tried, so can't speak from personal experience.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't want to monkey with Windows at all if at all possible, but it's looking like there may not be any other way.

Answer (score -2):

Format the stick in FAT format, then create truecrypt image on it.